# How to upload a file using the new controller actions format in sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, waterline

Someone know how I could upload a file to a controller action using the (inputs, exists) format of sails.js, this is my try:

```
  module.exports = {


  friendlyName: 'Upload file recording',


  description: 'Upload a recording to AWS',

  inputs: {
    name: {
      required: true,
      type: 'string'
    },
    mimeType: {
      required: true,
      type: 'string'
    },
    recording: {
      type: 'ref'
    }
  },

  exits: {

    noRecordings: {
      responseType: 'no recordings',
      description: `You don't have any recording for this event`,
    },
    serverError: {
      responseType: 'server error',
      description: `Failed to upload the file`,
    }

  },


  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {

    //  fixme    
    inputs.file('recording').upload({
      adapter: require('skipper-s3'),
      key: process.env.AWS_S3_KEY,
      secret: process.env.AWS_S3_SECRET,
      bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKETNAME
    }, function (err, filesUploaded) {
      if (err) return exits.serverError(err);
      return exits.success({
        files: filesUploaded,
        textParams: req.allParams()
      });
    });

  }
};
```

The upload files because the inputs.file is not a function. So basically the question is, how can I pass a file here.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So finally found the solution to that, I just need to use:

```
files: ['recording'],
```

in addition to:

```
inputs:
 recording: {
      example: '===',
      required: true
 },
```

And then inside the action function:

```
inputs.recording.upload({
      adapter: require('skipper-s3'),
      key: process.env.AWS_S3_KEY,
      secret: process.env.AWS_S3_SECRET,
      bucket: process.env.AWS_S3_BUCKETNAME
    }, function (err, filesUploaded) {
      if (err) return exits.serverError(err);
      console.log(filesUploaded);
      return exits.success(newFileRecording);
    });
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very useful seeing as the official Sails docs have not been updated to reflect action2 format. I would only add that for me it doesn't work unless you add `type: 'ref'` to the input.

Comment: Where should i add the 'files : ["recording"]'?

Comment: @MazharAli I believe it was in the controller action file, as one of the parameters `inside module.exports = {}`

Comment: It works fine for ejs but doesn't work for FormData() when I tried in react application