# Upload file with Sails JS and Vue JS

Tags: vue.js, file-upload, sails.js

I want to upload a file with Parasails. But I have a error :

```
<- POST /api/v1/admin/create-article          (3ms 400)
 |  no file attached
 |  No file was attached.
 °
```

I suppose to my syntaxe is not good.
My html code :

```
    <div class="form-group">
     <label for="imgFile">Image:</label>
      <input class="form-control-file" id="imgFile"  type="file" :class="[formErrors.imgFile ? 'is-invalid' : '']" autocomplete="imgFile">  
      <div class="invalid-feedback" v-if="formErrors.imgFile">S'il vous plaît, entrez une image valide.</div>
     </div>
```

My action 2 :

```
module.exports = {
    files: ['imgFile'], 

  friendlyName: 'Create article',

  description: '',

  inputs: {
     imgFile: {
      description: 'Upstream for an incoming file upload.',
      type: 'ref'
     },   
    titre: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
    },
    description: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
    },
    contenue: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
    },

    postDate:{
      type: 'string',
      required: false,
    },

    etiquette:{
      type: 'number',
      required: false,
    },

    sharingLink:{
      type: 'string',
      required: false,
    }
  },


  exits: {
    success: {
      outputDescription: 'The newly created `Thing`.',
      outputExample: {}
    },

    noFileAttached: {
      description: 'No file was attached.',
      responseType: 'badRequest'
    },

    tooBig: {
      description: 'The file is too big.',
      responseType: 'badRequest'
    },
  },


  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
    var util = require('util');

    // Upload the image.
    var info = await sails.uploadOne(inputs.imgFile, {
      maxBytes: 3000000
    })
    // Note: E_EXCEEDS_UPLOAD_LIMIT is the error code for exceeding
    // `maxBytes` for both skipper-disk and skipper-s3.
    .intercept('E_EXCEEDS_UPLOAD_LIMIT', 'tooBig')
    .intercept((err)=>new Error('The photo upload failed: '+util.inspect(err)));

    if(!info) {
      throw 'noFileAttached';
    }


    var unurl = await sails.helpers.convertUrl(inputs.titre);
    await Article.create({titre:inputs.titre, description:inputs.description, contenue:inputs.contenue ,postDate:inputs.postDate ,sharingLink:inputs.sharingLink,url:unurl, etiquette:inputs.etiquette}).fetch();
    return exits.success();



  }
};
```

My Root :

```
  'POST /api/v1/admin/create-article':                    { action: 'admin/create-article' },
```

I have add this package on my project : sails-hook-uploads

I'm new to Sails and I do not understand this error.
Thanks!
[How to upload a file using the new controller actions format in sails.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50477645/how-to-upload-a-file-using-the-new-controller-actions-format-in-sails-js)

Comment: You need to clarify if it's server side problem or client side problem.
Is the file uploaded to sails.js? You can investigate on chrome dev tool.
If the file is not attached to request at all, the problem is on the server side. 
If the file is attached on the request, the server not handling the request in the right way.

Comment: Just in case, make sure you are not using websocket request. Sails.js has great integration with websocket but websocket can't send files. Also, websocket requests may not appear on dev tools.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you for your answers !

I think it's a front-end problem. When I make a "console.log" on "inputs" in my action:

```
{ imgFile: 
   Upstream {
     _fatalErrors: [],
     isNoop: true,
     _files: [],
     timeouts: { untilFirstFileTimer: [Object], untilMaxBufferTimer: [Object] },
     _readableState: 
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: true,
        highWaterMark: 16,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: null,
        ended: false,
        endEmitted: false,
        reading: false,
        sync: true,
        needReadable: false,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: true,
     domain: null,
     _events: { error: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 1,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     fieldName: 'NOOP_imgFile' },
  titre: 'inputs inputs inputs inputs',
  description: 'inputs inputs inputs',
  contenue: 'inputs inputs inputs',
  postDate: '2019-12-21T09:13',
  etiquette: 1 }
```

On the Chrome dev tool :

[response of the tool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAhP1.png)

I think is not a websocket request is XMLHttpRequest (type;xhr).

Answer (score 0):

```
module.exports = {


  friendlyName: 'Update profile avatar',


  description: '',


  inputs: {

  },


  exits: {

    success: {
      responseType: 'redirect'
    },

    failure: {
      responseType: 'redirect'
    },

    unhandleError: {
      responseType: 'redirect',
    }

  },


  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {

    let req = this.req;
    let res = this.res;

    req.file('avatar').upload({
        saveAs: fileName,
        dirname: require('path').resolve(sails.config.appPath, 
                'assets/uploads')
    }, function whenDone(err, uploadedFile) { 
        // your code here
    });
  }


};
```

This is my code in controller when using req.file('file-name').upload() function. No need to define file in inputs because using req

Comment: I added "enctype='multipart/form-data'" but it did not change anything. I also add the attribute "name" to my input "File". I also tried with "this.req.file.upload" and the error: "Upstream (file upload: `imgFile`) emitted an error: { Error: EMAXBUFFER: An Upstream (`NOOP_imgFile`) timed out before it was plugged into a receiver. It was still unused after waiting 4500ms. You can configure this timeout by changing the `maxTimeToBuffer` option."

Comment: I have edit the answer with my upload code. Please check and try it.